# jQuery todo list cross off items

Tags: jquery

I've developed a todo list with jQuery and now I want to cross off completed items.
How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<title>Test02 - ToDo List</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="try.js"></script>


<body>  
    add new item: </br>
    <div id = "container">
        <input id="txtin" type="text" />
        <button id="btnin">Add</button>
        </br>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnin").click(function(){
        $("#container").append('<span><input type="checkbox" id="chck">' + $("#txtin").val() + '<br /></span>');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css to strike through the text, and you can use jQuery to add and remove the class as the checkboxes are checked and unchecked.

Also, as an FYI, you do not want to have multiple html elements with the same id, so I changed the id "chck" to a class.

**CSS**

```
.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnin").click(function(){
        $("#container").append('<span><input type="checkbox" class="chck">' + $("#txtin").val() + '<br /></span>');

        $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (this.checked) {
                $this.parent().addClass('completed');
            } else {
                $this.parent().removeClass('completed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgyogmch/1/) of it working.

Comment: because i have this first line:   $(document).ready(function(){         and i need this line for the first function...

Comment: Then take the function and insert it into the document.ready function.  I have updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: ok.. I forgot to put <link rel="stylesheet" href="test02.css" /> in the html... tnx a lot!!!!!!

Comment: If that has resolved your issue, please upvote / accept the answer

Comment: I upvoted and it does'nt accept.. I have 1 more quastion... I want all the chosen chckbox to be in end of my list... how can I do it?